On small remark to Theorem 1.14 in Folland's Real analysis
From here and here we can read about Theorem 1.14 in Folland's Real analysis text and its proof respectively.

1.14 Theorem Let $\mathcal A \subset \mathcal{P}(X)$ be an algebra, $\mu_0$ be a premeasure on $\mathcal A$, and $\mathcal{M}$ the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}$. There exists a measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{M}$ whose restriction to $\mathcal{A}$ is $\mu_0$, namely $\mu=\mu^\star|\mathcal{M}$ where $\mu^\star$ is given by $(1.12)$. If $\nu$ is another measure on $\mathcal{M}$ that extends $\mu_0$, then $\nu(E)\leq \mu(E)$ for all $E\in \mathcal{M}$, with equality when $\mu(E)\leq \infty$. If $\mu_0$ is $\sigma$-finite, then $\mu$ is the unique extension of $\mu_0$ to a measure on $\mathcal{M}$.


Proof. The first assertion follows from Carathéodory's theorem and Proposition 1.13 since the $\sigma$-algebra of $\mu^*$-measurable sets includes $\mathcal A$ and hence $\mathcal{M}$. As for the second assertion, if $E \in \mathcal{M}$ and $E \subset \bigcup_{1}^{\infty} A_j$ where $A_j \in \mathcal A$, then $\nu(E) \leq \sum_{1}^{\infty} \nu(A_j) = \sum_{1}^{\infty} \mu_0(A_j)$, whence $\nu(E) \leq \mu(E)$. Also, if we set $A = \bigcup_{1}^{\infty} A_j$, we have
$$
\nu(A) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \nu \left( \bigcup_{1}^{n} A_j \right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu \left( \bigcup_{1}^{n} A_j \right) = \mu(A).
$$
If $\mu(E) < \infty$, we can choose the $A_j$'s so that $\mu(A) < \mu(E) + \epsilon$, hence $\mu(A \setminus E) < \epsilon$, and
$$
\mu(E) \leq \mu(A) = \nu(A) = \nu(E) + \nu(A \setminus E) \leq \nu(E) + \mu(A \setminus E) \leq \nu(E) + \epsilon.
$$
Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, $\mu(E) = \nu(E)$. Finally, suppose $X = \bigcup_{1}^{\infty} A_j$ with $\mu_0(A_j) < \infty$, where we can assume that the $A_j$'s are disjoint. Then for any $E \in \mathcal{M}$,
$$
\mu(E) = \sum_{1}^{\infty} \mu(E \cap A_j) = \sum_{1}^{\infty} \nu(E \cap A_j) = \nu(E),
$$
so $\nu = \mu$. $\qquad{\blacksquare}$

There's also equation $(1.12)$, which reads
$$\mu^\ast(E)=\inf\left\{\sum_1^\infty \mu_0(A_j):A_j\in\mathcal{A},E\subset\bigcup_1^\infty A_j\right\}\tag{1.12}.$$
After the proof of the theorem, Folland remarks:

The proof of this theorem yields more than the statement. Indeed, $\mu_0$ may be extended to a measure on the algebra $\mathcal{M}^\ast$ of all $\mu^\ast$-measurable sets.

I've been thinking about this remark for some time and I don't think I understand what he is trying to say. If we have a premeasure, it induces by $(1.12)$ an outer measure, which (by Carathéodory's theorem, not shown) restricted to $\mathcal{M}^\ast$ yields a complete measure. In this sense, we've extended $\mu_0$ to a complete measure on $\mathcal{M}^\ast$, which might be larger than $\mathcal M$. Is this what his remark is trying to say? I'm simply a bit confused about the placement of this remark, since I don't see the direct connection to Theorem 1.14.

I think my interpretation is more or less correct. To repeat myself, I think his remark is saying that we can get an extension of $\mu_0$ to a $\sigma$-algebra potentially larger than $\sigma(\mathcal{A})=\mathcal{M}$, namely the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{M}^\ast$ of all $\mu^\ast$-measurable sets. Call this complete measure $\overline{\mu}=\mu^\ast|\mathcal{M}^\ast$. I guess all one cares about (but not always) is the restriction of $\overline{\mu}$ to $\mathcal{M}$, which may not be a complete measure.

Your interpretation is correct, the connection to the proof lies in the very first statement.
This theorem (1.14) only claims that there is a measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{M}$. As you noted, in the first statement of the proof Folland invokes Caratheodory's theorem and the previous Proposition (1.13) to (implicitly) extend $\mu_0$ all the way to an outer measure $\mu^*$ which gives a complete measure when restricted to $\mathcal{M}^*$, the $\sigma$-algebra of all $\mu^*$-measurable sets.
However, for the sake of this Theorem he is only interested in the fact that $\mu^*\rvert_{\mathcal{M}}$ is a measure with our desired properties, so he discards the "larger" measure $\mu^*\rvert_{\mathcal{M^*}}$ for the sake of just considering $\mu:=\mu^*\rvert_{\mathcal{M}}$. I think the Remark was just intended to point out that this discarding was intentional and the first statement really gives more than just what he used in the proof, as in your observations.
